# LaTeX в plotly (R)

Tags: r, latex

Подскажите, пожалуйста, по такому вопросу, если кто-то сталкивался.
Использую в R [пакет plotly](https://plot.ly/r/). Согласно руководствам на сайте, должна быть поддержка LaTeX, html-тегов для форматирования текста, а также гиперссылок. Пытаюсь нарисовать красивое, как в [примере](https://plot.ly/r/LaTeX/) - а красивое не получается.

Вот код из примера:

```
library(plotly)
plot_ly(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4), y = c(1, 4, 9, 16),
        name = "$\\alpha_{1c} = 352 \\pm 11 \\text{ km s}^{-1}$") %>%
  add_trace(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4), y = c(0.5, 2, 4.5, 8),
            name = "$\\beta_{1c} = 25 \\pm 11 \\text{ km s}^{-1}$") %>%
  layout(xaxis = list(title = "$\\sqrt{(n_\\text{c}(t|{T_\\text{early}}))}$"),
         yaxis = list(title = "$d, r \\text{ (solar radius)}$"))
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Работающий пример, где есть все, кроме LaTeX-овских выражений:

```
plot_ly(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4), y = c(1, 4, 9, 16)) %>%
    layout(xaxis = 
               list(title = "H<sub>2</sub>O <a href='https://plot.ly/'>Plotly</a>"),
           yaxis = list(title = "----"),
           annotations = 
               list(text = "<a href='https://plot.ly/'>Plotly</a>"))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
И тут, если в подписи к оси Y вместо "----" прописать что-то вида $...$, все ломается - ни подписи, ни точек с линией (как показано выше).

Что я делаю не так? Как добиться желаемого? Спасибо.

Windows 7, R 3.2.3, все пакеты актуальных версий, RStudio Pre 0.99.837 (на крайней "стабильной" версии, которая не Pre, все то же самое).

Comment: Если открыть сохранённый из RStudio Viewer html в браузере и запустить консоль javascript, то выдаётся ошибка: `ReferenceError: MathJax is not defined`. В Linux баг тоже восрпоизводится, так что можно смело писать репорт сюда: https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это баг текущей версии [`plotly`](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly). В пакете не содержится библиотека MathJax и она не подключена в качестве зависимости при формирование объекта `htmlwidgets`.

Собственно, решение. Если планируете вставлять код на сайт, то необходимо подключать MathJax скрипт на страницах сайта, где будут размещаться графики.

Достичь удовлетворительного результата с пакетом `rmarkdown` на данный момент можно только путём редактирования шаблона. Т.е. необходимо скопировать шаблон по умолчанию для html-файлов, внести туда код подключения и настройки MathJax и в YAML блоке rmd-файла указываем наш шаблон. Подробнее об использовании шаблонов можно узнать в соответствующем разделе документации: http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/developer_document_templates.html.

Comment: Спасибо, но так тоже не работает. В смысле, я вручную загружаю library(rmarkdown), но вижу все ту же картину и на вкладке Viewer в RStudio, в и итоговом html. Нету не только LaTeX-овской надписи, но и точек с линией (которые были, если не использовать LaTeX). Более того, точки на самом деле  есть (водишь мышью по графику - всплывают подсказки), только их не видно.

Comment: Ради проверки вставил `$\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}$` в сам текст документа (не внутри R-чанка) - работает, как обычно. Запостил про баг, авось исправят: https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/375

Comment: Действительно, не работает. Можно использовать функцию `plotly_POST()` для отправки графика на сервер plotly и вставки его в iframe, но это костыль.

Comment: В html, сгенерированном с помощью markdown, не работает, потому что MathJax подключается в самом конце документа. Если отредактировать файл вручную и подключить скрипт внутри head, то всё работает.

Comment: Добавил `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>`, теперь оно выглядит вот так: http://i081.radikal.ru/1512/9a/899a6c6f7f53.jpg Видимо, буду ждать, пока пофиксят, чтобы без костылей работало.

Comment: По умолчанию MathJax не обрабатывает `$$`. Надо его преднастроить. http://mathjax.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tex.html#tex-and-latex-math-delimiters